# What does 1811 British Monthly Magazine mean by the form: At [place], [person]?

Tags: england, 1810s

I found a [British Monthly Magazine from 1811](https://books.google.com/books?id=7fmMGTY2lDYC&pg=PA592) that states in part at the second paragraph starting on that page:

> At Kemerton, Miss Mumford.
>   At Cheltenham, P. Evans, esq. of Abergavenny.
>   At Stroud, Mrs. Newman, wife of Mr. N. attorney.
>   At Cirencester, Mr. Pierce, druggist.

But I cannot figure out what they mean.  Is this a birth announcement?  I think not since adjacent entries give the profession of males.  Is it a death announcement? I read the prior paragraphs and don't understand the context.

What does it mean for this magazine to state: At *place*, *person*.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are death notices.

Go to the previous page, two paragraphs up from the bottom, and you will see the small heading: *Died.]*

---

Just for kicks, here are, I believe, the relevant burials:
Kemerton burials: 4 Jun 1811, Catherine Anne Mumford, aged 22 yrs
Stroud burials: 10 Jun 1811, Arabella wife of Charles Newman, age 39
Cirencester burials: 28 May 1811, John Pierce, Druggist

I couldn't see Mr Evans' burial, perhaps he was buried in Wales.

Comment: The next long entry which describes the person's illness is also a clue that these are death notices.